# Was Samson permitted to commit suicide and if so why?

Tags: shoftim--book-of, suicide, shimshon-samson

In [Judges 16:30](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.16.30?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) Samson commits suicide.

> Samson cried, “Let me die with the Philistines!

See Metzudat David there

Seemingly his supernatural strength had returned, perhaps only temporarily. But, rather than use this strength to escape and live to fight another day he chose to commit suicide. I am unaware of any source which says that Samson committed a sin (and have seen it said that he in fact performed a kiddush Hashem). I would like to know if Samson was in fact permitted to commit suicide and if so why?

Comment: How do you know he committed suicide? Maybe he was hoping to escape. It was a risky war maneuver that didn't fully succeed. cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roi_Klein

Comment: I've always understood that the fact the collapse killed him was because Hashem withdrew the supernatural strength again - if so there was no suicide.

Comment: It's not 100% clear that this is called suicide. In reading the text, it appears that his main focus was to kill the Philistines knowing that he would be killed along with them. It's likely that he assumed that they were going to kill him, anyway and that he knew that God wasn't going to restore his strength or vision. He didn't want to die without his persecutors dying as well. (@AlBerko's #3 comment is also highly likely.)

Comment: I don't know if any of the commentators/downvoter read the verse I referenced but I quote it now partially. It seems pretty evident from the plain meaning of the text as well as the standard commentaries that he intended to commit suicide. Opinions to the contrary should source their contention

Comment: No, it doesn't seem evident from the plain meaning that he intended to commit suicide.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's not an argument, merely contradiction

Comment: And your question is only predicated on mere assertion. What more do you expect?

Comment: @DoubleAA ^^ http://www.montypython.net/scripts/argument.php

Comment: @postinganonymously :)

Comment: Per the Zohar in Parshat Nasa, Samson voluntarily wished to die in this world AND  the next ....
וְאִית מַאן דְּאָמַר, דְּלֵית לֵיהּ חוּלָקָא בְּהַהוּא עָלְמָא. מַאי טַעְמָא בְּגִין דְּאָמַר (שופטים ט״ז:ל׳) תָמוּת נַפְשִׁי עִם פְּלִשְׁתִּים, וּמָסַר חוּלָקֵיהּ בְּחוּלָקָא דִּפְלִשְׁתָּאֵי, דִּיְּמוּת נַפְשֵׁיהּ עִמְּהוֹן בְּהַהוּא עָלְמָא.
"Some say that he has no part in that world. Why is that? It is because he said, "Let my Nefesh die with the Philistines" (Shoftim 16:30) and he passed his lot with the lot of the Philistines, so that his Nefesh will die with them in that world."

Answer (score 3):

Simplest answer: Before Samson attempts this suicide mission he prays (Jud. 16:28) that God grant him strength one last time so that he may take revenge, [God then grants his request] whereupon, with superhuman strength, Samson successfully demolished the place; ergo, God approved (or, “in fact permitted”) the suicide mission. As to the “why?”, scripture doesn’t express God’s reason, at least not explicitly (see parenthesis below).

(WADR, I’m sure a rather simple google search would yield many results; this is a classic, old question discussed by many.)